# How does weather forecasting work in production settings?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, meteorology

The way I understand time series models is that you usually have to .fit() them every time you want to make a forecast. This is because there might be trends that were not seen before and so you can't see too much in the future.

My question is: is it possible to fit it once to get all the parameters and then just forecast() using unseen data *assuming my data is stationary*.

For example:

```
data = [y_1, ..., y_n, y_n+1, ..., y_m]
```

Train the model on [y_1, ..., y_n] then do something like fit.predict([y_n+1, ..., y_m]) to get forecast for y_m+1.

I know I can do fit.forecast(steps = m-(n+1)), but such a forecast would not take into account all of y_n+1...y_m data that I've observed since the model was trained.

As I said, ideally, I'd fit() it at every prediction time, but because of the nature of the problem that may be computationally hard.

The problem I'm tackling is similar to weather forecasting or stock prediction for a lot of different stocks (each point in the map would have a different history and trends, just like different stocks).

What's the best way to go about it?

I know I could also train an XGB Regressor or other regressor using lagged variables, but I'm curious about how to do it with time series.

Comment: Weather forecasting isn't a good example because it doesn't work with empirical correlations. We understand the underlying *physics* well enough to write down big partial differential equations that approximate what the atmosphere is doing and approximately solve them on supercomputers.